# Can I build my jQuery promise pipe chain without using eval()?

Tags: javascript, jquery, eval, promise

I need a promise pipe chain which for this example looks like this:

```
populateOfferSettings().pipe(populateSegmentationSettings).pipe(populateHousehold).pipe(viewReady);
```

This is generated dynamically and could contain many functions, provided as an array. I've figured out a way of doing this but it relies on `eval()`. User input isn't a factor here as this function is only used by developers to manage presenting views so I don't feel too bad about using it (I understand the pitfalls), but I'd feel better not doing so.

Here's my code:

```
//Array of functions (generally provided as a function parameter)
var requiredFunctions = [
    'populateOfferSettings',
    'populateSegmentationSettings',
    'populateHousehold'
];

//Start building code string to evaluate later, starting with first required function
var code = requiredFunctions[0] + '()';

//Process each required function after first
$.each(requiredFunctions.slice(1), function (index, functionName) {
    //Add function to code string using pipe()
    code += '.pipe(' + functionName + ')';
});

//Add viewReady() to code string as this should always be at the end
code += '.pipe(viewReady);';

//Evaluate code string
eval(code);
```

Is there another way of handling piping of functions that would eliminate the need for `eval()` without making this much more verbose? It seems like there should be but I'm finding it difficult to get my head around jQuery's promise functionality, especially as I'm currently limited to jQuery 1.7.1 before the documentation and functionality of these things were changed.

Comment: how is the function list provided originally ? as an array of strings ?

Comment: Yes, just strings. So `thisFunction()` would be referred to as `'thisFunction'` in the array

Comment: @RyanWilliams Does it *have* to be an array of strings? Accepting an array of function references to use would allow you to get rid of the use of `eval`.

Comment: @AnthonyGrist I don't think they need to be strings, no.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Per conversation below with @AnthonyGrist:

```
var code = requiredFunctions[0]();

for (var i=1; i<requiredFunctions.length; i++)
   code = code.pipe(window[requiredFunctions[i]]);
```

if the requiredFunctions are strings, and defined in `window` scope.

---

And `code = code.pipe(requiredFunctions[i]);` if they are functions.

Was also thinking about using `code = code.pipe(new Function(requiredFunctions[i]))` but that's practically the same as `window` approach. (only the scopes will change, sheesh...)

Comment: That would only work if `requiredFunctions` held function references rather than strings.

Comment: @AnthonyGrist after a lot commenting (and deleting of comments :D), how about this approach? As long as the functions are defined, the references for them exist in the window

Comment: Not sure there's a guarantee they'd exist in the `window` object (they could be scoped to another function). However, Ryan has said he doesn't *have* to accept an array of strings - your original answer with an array of actual function references being passed in would likely be the best option.